# How to derive which type matches a generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following types…

```
interface ParentNode {
    items: Node[]
}

interface LeafNode {
}

type Node = ParentNode | LeafNode

function List<Nodes extends unknown[]>(items: Nodes)
```

…how can I derive whether the `unknown` type passed to `Nodes` matches the `ParentNode` type (i.e. has `items` property) or a `LeafNode` type?

```
interface A1 {
    items: []
}

interface A2 {
    name: string;
}

List<A1|A2>([
    { name: 'Hello' },
    { items: [
          { name: 'Bye' }
          { items: [] }
      ] }
])

// in the List function

if ('items' in item) {
    let typedItem = item as A1 // desired effect but I'm aware it's not possible like this
} else {
    let typedItem = item as A2 // desired effect but I'm aware it's not possible like this
}
```

How can I do this even though the `List` function does not know which types `Nodes` can be in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would add an attribute, say `type`, in the interface to assist the process:

```js
interface Base {
  type: 'foo' | 'bar';
  // ... some other common attr
}

// Leaf
interface Bar extends Base {
  type: 'bar';
  name: string;
  // attrs?: any[];
  // items?: Bar[];
}

// Parent
interface Foo extends Base {
  type: 'foo';
  items: Bar[];
}

type Baz = Foo | Bar; // no `Base` here

function isBaz(item: unknown): item is Baz {
  if (typeof item !== 'object' || item === null) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!('type' in item)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!('items' in item) && !('name' in item)) {
    return false;
  }

  // more checks
  return true;
}

function List<T extends unknown = unknown>(items: T[]) {
  // items is array of anything
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (isBaz(item)) {
      // item is now T & Baz
      if (item.type === 'foo') {
        // item should be `Foo` here
        console.log(item.items); // []
        return;
      }
  
      // item should be `Bar` here
      console.log(item.name); // Hello
    }
  });
}

List([
  {
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Hello',
  },
  {
    type: 'foo',
    items: [],
  },
]);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it if `function List` needs to be generic?

Comment: does `function List<T extends Baz>(items: T[]) {}` satisfy your requirement? the implementation is the same as the first part

Comment: It doesn't, it needs to be unknown: `function List<T extends unknown[]>(items: T) {}`. I've tried something similar to what you suggested (i.e. passing known types to `T`) but that made `function List` too specific. I'm trying to see if it is even possible in Typescript. What do you think?

Comment: that means the function will assume to be taking anything and ts will still check the type when you write `List<Foo>(items)`, you would need some assertion function. See the updated example

Comment: Thanks, I found out along the way that my problem was slightly different than what I presented here. Had to use `Extract` to get what I needed.